# Add width to element with count up effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to make a simple animation with jQuery. For example when I have a percentage of 60% which needs to get set to a div I want to add it with a count up function via jQuery to show an animation of the element increasing step by step until 60% is set. This is my code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: blog;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
}

.inner {
  display: blog;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner" style="width: 60%;">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not using a simple transition?

Comment: Oh it's you again. I want to add the percentage from the progress bar after document ready to show the user an animation of the increasing progress bar. So when he opens the page the percentage should count up do a defined level.

Comment: yes a transition : https://jsfiddle.net/jsqt1z60/

Comment: NOTE: I prefer @TemaniAfif answer :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh cool, thats simple. Thank you!

Comment: I've just updated @TemaniAfif example work https://jsfiddle.net/jsqt1z60/1/

Answer (score 0):

I changed a few bits and pieces. and did not use jQuery (sorry).

```js
const percentage = 60;
var currPer = 5;
var pBar = document.getElementById("inner");

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  let progressInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (currPer < percentage) {
      currPer += 5;
      pBar.style.width = `${currPer}%`;
      console.log(currPer);
    } else {
      cancelInterval(progressInterval);
    }
  }, 500);

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: blog;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
}

#inner {
  display: blog;
  background: red;
  width: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="inner">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function with `setTimeout`:

```js
   
$(document).ready(function(){
  function update_progress(_val){
    if (_val <= 60){
      $('.inner').css('width', _val.toString()+'%');
      setTimeout(function(){
         update_progress(_val+1);
      }, 100);
    }
  }
  update_progress(0);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: blog;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
}

.inner {
  display: blog;
  background: red;
  width: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="inner">

 </div>
</div>
```